# One's Complement in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim, ones-complement

I am trying to find the one-s complement of a binary number using MIPS in QtSpim.

Firstly I measure the string length and then check if a character is 0 or not making the necessary transformations.

The following code always returns "000..0". Any help in fixing this will be highly appreciated

```
   .data
    promptStr:     .asciiz "Please enter a binary string:"
    string:        .space 120
   .text

     main: 
     la $a0, promptStr
     li $v0, 4
     syscall

     la $a0, string
     li $a1, 30
     li $v0, 8
     syscall

     move $s0, $a0   #save the string in $s0 because $a0 may change         
     

     countLength:

     la $t0, 0($s0)

     loop:
     lb   $t1, 0($t0)
     beq  $t1, $zero end

     addi $t0, $t0, 1
     j loop

     end:

     la $t1, 0($s0)
     sub $t3 $t0 $t1 #$t3 now contains the length of the string
     addi $t3,$t3,-1
     
     
     
     la $a0, string
     li $t1,0
     while:
  beq $t1,$t3,exit #$t3 is the string length
  la $a1,string
  addu $a2,$a1,$t1   # $a1 = &str[x].  assumes x is in $t1
  add $t7,$t1,$a0
  
  bne $a2,'1',ELS  #checks if i-th charcter is not 1
  li $t0, '1'      # puts 1 in places of 0
  
  sb $t0, ($t7)
  la $a0, string
  
  ELS: 
  li $t0, '0'     #puts 0 in places of 1
  sb $t0, ($t7)
  la $a0, string
  
  addi $t1,1
  
  j while
  exit:   
  
  li $v0, 4 # syscall for string print   
  syscall


    

li $v0, 10      # end program
syscall
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug it?  Use single step to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: MIPS bitwise not (ones-complement inverse) is done with `nor $t0, $t1, $zero`.  Or if you're converting to a base-2 string as well, yeah you could do it on the fly with `'1' - (num&1)` instead of `'0' + (num&1)`.  No need for any branching, other than a loop.